# Linux. MySQL command-line client. Set '--sigint-ignore' option forever

Tags: mysql, console, sigint

I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is required sometimes but I can't remember I needed it. Sometimes I'm trying to copy output text by pressing that "hotkey" automatically and losing db connection instead. It is very annoying and I would like to disable SIGINT sending forever. Can this be done?

Sysinfo: Linux Mint 17 mysql-client-5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (or wherever your my.cnf is):

```
[mysql]
sigint-ignore
```

Add it to an existing `[mysql]` section if you already have one...